# Rails Handling Nil in Class Method Chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following Search class method that takes a bunch of params and then builds a request.

```
def self.search(agent, params)
  RealPropertySale.where(id: available_ids)
                      .joins(:address)
                      .by_state(state)
                      .by_suburb(suburb)
                      .by_post_code(post_code)
                      .by_country(country)
                      .paginate(page: page)
end

def self.by_state(state)
  where(addresses: {state: state})
end

def self.by_suburb(suburb)
  where(addresses: {suburb: suburb})
end

def self.by_post_code(post_code)
  where(addresses: {post_code: post_code})
end

def self.by_country(country)
  where(addresses: {country: country})
end
```

What is the correct way of handling if one of my custom class methods e.g. `self.by_country(country)` returns nil so that the query continues with whatever param/s are present. I have tried returning self if one the params is blank but the query is lost and the class is returned resulting in errors.

Comment: `self.by_country(country)` should not be returning `nil`. It should be returning an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` with an empty set and you can chain more where queries to it.

Comment: Note that you should only chain queries that have proper criteria.  If the `country` is not specified, chaining `by_country(country)` will produce an SQL statement with no rows, so your query would fail with otherwise valid criteria.  You can choose which chain methods to call in `self.search` to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Michael Gaskill that you probably should only call the scopes that actually affect the final query (i.e. that have meaningful params).

However, if you insist on the scopes ignoring `nil` parameters, you may make them **return `current_scope` instead** (which is an [undocumented](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping.rb#L13) but useful method):

```
def self.by_state(state)
  return current_scope if state.nil?
  where(addresses: {state: state})
end
```

Comment: I agree with @Michael Gaskill and have adjusted my code accordingly. In regards to your answer I found that you can either `all` or `current_scope`.

Answer (score 1):

We did something similar by breaking it down like so :

```
response = RealPropertySale.where(id: available_ids)
                  .joins(:address)
response = response.by_state(state)          if state
response = response.by_suburb(suburb)        if suburb
response = response.by_post_code(post_code)  if post_code
response = response.by_country(country)      if country
response = response.paginate(page: page)     if page
```

I like the readibility. I try to break it down to as many pieces as needed, but this should be adapted to your business logic. Don't know if, for you, it makes sense to check if suburb is provided for example.